# Force Kable to render table as 1 row

Tags: r, shiny, kable

I am trying to get kable to render a table as 1 row in HTML for a Shiny app.

```
    arrow_table <- data.frame(
      symbol = c("\u25B2", "~", "\u25BC"),
      text = c("Greater than 1% growth", "Minimal change +/- 1%", "Greater than 1% decrease"),
      color = c("green", "black", "red")
    )
    
    arrow_table$symbol <- sprintf("<span style='color:%s'>%s</span>", arrow_table$color, arrow_table$symbol) 
    
    kbl(
      arrow_table,
      caption = "",
      booktabs = T,
      col.names = c(" ", " ", " "),
      escape = F
    ) %>%
      kable_styling("striped", full_width = F, position = "center")
  }
```

[image: 3 rows 1 column table]

I am somewhat forced to do it this way since I can't get footnote text to display colors and I need to display the colors of the arrows for the users.

I tried using a footnote tag and it wouldn't display the colors of the arrows so I figured that I could make a 1 row by 3 column table at the bottom of my main table to display information about the arrows (\u25B2 is up arrow which must be green, \u25BC is a down arrow which must be red). This is the closest I've gotten to rendering correctly but I get a 3 row by 1 column table with this code.

Any help to get a 1 row by 3 column legend table would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's an option:

```r
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(kableExtra)

arrow_table <- data.frame(
  symbol = c("\u25B2", "~", "\u25BC"),
  text = c("Greater than 1% growth", "Minimal change +/- 1%", "Greater than 1% decrease"),
  color = c("green", "black", "red")
)

arrow_table$symbol <- sprintf("<span style='color:%s'>%s</span>", arrow_table$color, arrow_table$symbol) 

all <- arrow_table %>% 
  mutate(
    all = paste0(symbol, " ", text, " ", color)
  ) %>% 
  select(all) %>% 
  pivot_wider(names_from = all, values_from = all)


kbl(all ,
  caption = "",
  booktabs = T,
  col.names = c(" ", " ", " "),
  escape = F
) %>%
  kable_styling("striped", full_width = F, position = "center")
```

[image]

Comment: I thought about trying dplyr but wasn't sure if Kable had a built in approach to this. Thanks for the solution!